# Why was this old post turned into a Community Wiki?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, community-wiki

I was browsing around and came to this old post, which I have seen a few times before: [How should I deal with an employee who has slept with my wife?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/7617/73791)

However, I happened to notice that such post is a Community Wiki (as well as all the answers there posted). Checking the edits history, I can see it was made a Community Wiki (by [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/8434/david-blaine) 110 rep user) about 3 months after it was posted.

The user who made the post a Wiki seems unreachable (last seen on '13), but I still wonder **why was this post turned into a Community Wiki?**

I can see this was before the [Stop using community wiki as a reputation denial mechanism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227290/332286) Meta SE post, where converting posts to CW was easier and even prone to abuse. However I still wonder how a low-rep user can/could do this<sup>1</sup>, and most importantly *why*... perhaps some of our respected users who witnessed this event can shed some light here.

<sup>1</sup> Another example, this time a 1 (?) rep user did the change as evidenced by [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/83/revisions) revisions.

Comment: FWIW back then this question has been [discussed at meta](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/605/168) quite thoroughly but nothing in that old discussion indicates an intent to make it CW. Per my reading of revisions history conversion happened on Oct 24 '13 which is when automatic triggering still worked, it was turned off only later - per rev history of referred MSE post it happened on Apr 9 '14

Comment: thanks @gnat actually, I landed on that question you linked, which led me to the CW post and noticing this situation. I'll read more about that automatic triggering.

Comment: another bit of info I found is, initially CW threshold here was 30 answers but it has [dropped to 15](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1659/168) on Jan 19 '13, this is somewhere between the question was asked and triggering answer was posted

Answer (score 1):

In both cases, the users "credited" with the CW conversion also answered the question and the timestamps line up.  Their answers kicked those questions over the threshold for automatic conversion, but instead of attributing the change to Community the revision history attributes it to the triggering user.

Your first example is hard to untangle, but on the second, the triggering answer was #20.  From the MSE post you link to it sounds like the threshold was at one time 30, but maybe it was 20 at some point.  I don't actually remember any more, though I remember being frustrated by it occasionally.

Comment: Curious behavior that one... that would have made many posts that reach HNQ Wikis when they got many answers/edits back in those days...if HNQ existed yet, that is. Talk about "wasted" rep.

Comment: I don't think HNQ was plastered onto every page back then.  There *was* a list (like there is now), but you had to go to it.